# How to search for distinguishedName in extended property in LDAP?

Tags: ldap

The user records in my company's LDAP data contain a field indicating
the manager-subordinate relationship, which contains the
distinguishedName for that employee's manager, like this:

```
CN=Some\\, Name,OU=WO1,OU=IT,OU=StandardUser,OU=ITUser,DC=emea,DC=foobar,DC=biz
```

I'd like to be able to search all employee that report to the same
person, by doing something like this in the query:

```
(manager=CN=Some\\, Name,OU=WO1,OU=IT,OU=StandardUser,OU=ITUser,DC=emea,DC=foobar,DC=biz)
```

but this doesn't seem to work (nor does it look right), nor do wildcard searches on the manager
field, which I was ready to use as a workaround.

I am using perl, with the Net::LDAP module, which is working perfectly
for other searches.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, a backslash `\` must be followed by two hexadecimal characters that define the byte that has been encoded.

Comment: Thanks @Terry - could you please be more specific in how that would apply to my search? and do the additional "="'s pose a problem too?